# is it possible to release a prepatch preminor and premajor using semantic-release?

Tags: gitlab, semantic-release

I'm trying to create prereleases to go with my normal releases.

when I do a prepatch merge to my release branch I would like my version to change from

```
1.0.0 
to 
1.0.1-rc-0
```

I know i can use prerelease like below, but this only incriments the last digit. 1.0.0-rc.0 to 1.0.0-rc.1

```
{"name": "rc", "channel": "rc", "prerelease": true}
```

but this only increments the last digit.

```
1.0.0-rc.0 
to 
1.0.0-rc.1
```

I want this to increment as if i was using npm version prepatch which would work like

```
1.0.0
1.0.1-rc.0
1.0.1-rc.1
1.0.1-rc.2
```